# Position a Modal to the current window - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog

I have actually created a modal pop-up which pops up when someone clicks on an element on my website.

However it always pops up at the top of the page / bottom of the page (where I have inserted the code.) Fixed, also isn't a good solution, as if the modal is long, it cannot be readed.

I basically want it to pop up for example 50px lower than the current window, so it will always pops up to the user, he/she doesn't have to scroll down/up.

Is there any plugin to solve this solution, in jQuery?

Comment: The modal plugin from Twitter Bootstrap will always popup the modal in the center of your screen. You might be able to position this differently, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Google search for: 'jQuery modal popup' gave me this http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/ – looks exactly like what you need.